# What does “ I had a U.S. visa, and it expired in 5 years.” mean?

Tags: prepositions, past-tense, prepositional-phrases

I can understand the former part of the sentence.

I had a U.S visa ( I used to have one, but I no longer have it.)

but I having trouble understanding the latter part of the sentence.

and it expired in 5 years. (the visa is no longer valid because "the 5 years already passed"? or the visa is still valid, and only valid for 5 years.)

Comment: It is ambiguous, meaning that the supplied sentence is ambiguous, it can mean either thing.

Comment: @banuyayi - It isn't ambiguous - it refers to a time in the past when the speaker's visa had five more years of validity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it being used in a larger context.

> [When/While I lived in Chicago] I had a U.S. Visa and it expired in five years.

- I am referring to a time in the past.  I am referring to *when I lived in Chicago.*  You know I am referring to a time in the past because I have used the past tense *had*.
- During this past time, I had a Visa. (Maybe I still do have it, such information is not provided in this sentence.)
- During the time that I lived in Chicago and had a Visa, that Visa was going to expire in five years.  So if I lived in Chicago in 2006, the Visa would expire in 2011.  This is a general observation on when the Visa would expire since we don't have absolute dates.

The purpose of this sentence is **not** to inform the listener **when** the Visa expired.  It is instead trying to inform the listener that in the past when I lived in Chicago, my Visa was valid for five years.

If you had visited me back *when I lived in Chicago and had a U.S. Visa* I might have said to you at that time, *I **have** a Visa and it **expires** in five years*.

Comment: this is super helpful!.

Answer (score 0):

If there is *no mistake* in the sentence, then the visa was obtained more than five years ago and has now expired.

It would be less ambiguous to say 'it expired after five years' or 'it expired in 2019'. 'In five years' makes you first think of a future event, which the totality of the sentence then makes you have to re-consider. It's not strictly *wrong*, it's just awkward.

Comment: I'm not sure that we be can be certain the Visa has expired.  Maybe you no longer have the Visa but it's still valid.  *I had a Visa and it expired in five years but I lost it two years after I received it.*

Comment: I qualified this with *If there is no mistake in the sentence*. We can't speculate on what wasn't said, only what was.

Comment: the sentence is correct.